# Error : ‘memcpy’ was not declared in this scope (Ubuntu 16.04, opencv2.4.13)

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, cmake

I'm trying to install opencv2.4.13 for Ubuntu 16.04 but getting an error like this when running `make` command.

```
[  1%] Built target opencv_core_pch_dephelp
[  1%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_core
[  2%] Building NVCC (Device) object modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/__/dynamicuda/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_matrix_operations.cu.o
/usr/include/string.h: In function ‘void* __mempcpy_inline(void*, const void*, size_t)’:
/usr/include/string.h:652:42: error: ‘memcpy’ was not declared in this scope
   return (char *) memcpy (__dest, __src, __n) + __n;
                                          ^
CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_matrix_operations.cu.o.cmake:266 (message):
  Error generating file
  /home/savvycom/opencv-2.4.13.6/release/modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/__/dynamicuda/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_generated_matrix_operations.cu.o


modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/build.make:198: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/__/dynamicuda/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_matrix_operations.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/__/dynamicuda/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_matrix_operations.cu.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:890: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My cmake configuration is:

```
cmake \
-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D CUDA_GENERATION=Kepler \
-D BUILD_LIBPROTOBUF_FROM_SOURCES=ON \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D PYTHON2_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python2.7 \
-D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python2.7 \
-D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR2=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7 \
-D PYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so \
-D PYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/ \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

Can someone please help me out with this.

Comment: Please include in your question the URL of the source package you downloaded and the commands you executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [a bug](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6500) in this version. It has been fixed in opencv master.

Open `cmake/OpenCVDetectCUDA.cmake`, on or around line 136, add the following line as noted [in this commit](https://github.com/Jmast/opencv/commit/c9c4e712c3704d48c954721c1320c4ab382f018a):

```
  set(OPENCV_CUDA_ARCH_FEATURES "${OPENCV_CUDA_ARCH_FEATURES} ${ARCH}")
    endif()
  endforeach()
+ set(NVCC_FLAGS_EXTRA ${NVCC_FLAGS_EXTRA} -D_FORCE_INLINES)

  # Tell NVCC to add PTX intermediate code for the specified architectures
  string(REGEX MATCHALL "[0-9]+" ARCH_LIST "${ARCH_PTX_NO_POINTS}")
```